# jquery open toggle from external link

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have developed this toggle menu that also displays a quote with each topic. Only thing I can't figure out is how to toggle a specific topic using a link from another page. Working example below. Thanks for looking.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $(".faqs dd").hide();
    $(".faqs dt").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".faqs dd").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".faqs dd:visible").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $(this).siblings(".faqs dt").removeClass("expanded");
  
  
  if($(".faqs dt").hasClass("expanded") == true) {
         // hide open subcontents
        $('.subcontent:visible').hide();
    $('.mainquote:visible').hide();
        // fade in new selected subcontent
        $('.subcontent[id='+$(this).attr('data-id')+']').delay(500).fadeIn();    
     } else {
      $('.subcontent:visible').hide(); } 
     
       }); 
     });
```

```css
dl dt,
dl dd {
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align:top;
  float:left;
   width:100%;
}


.faqs dt, .faqs dd { padding: 0 0 0 30px; margin: 2px 0 0px 0;
 -ms-word-break: normal;
 word-wrap: normal;
 -webkit-hyphens: none;
 -moz-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none; }

.faqs dt {font-weight:bold;} 

.faqs dt {cursor: pointer; background: url(http://www.evolvedstudio.com/plus_orange.png) no-repeat left; vertical-align:top; }
.faqs .expanded { background: url(http://www.evolvedstudio.com/minus_orange.png) no-repeat left; vertical-align:top; }

.subcontent {display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subcontent" id="123"><em>quote1</em></p></div>


<div class="subcontent" id="124"><em>quote2</em></p></div>

<dl class="faqs">

<dt data-id="123">Topic 1</dt>
<dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</dd>

<dt data-id="124">Topic 2</dt>
<dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "control from another page"?

Comment: I'd like to have a link on another page in a top level nav that goes to a page with this code and have that topic open. So for example if I'm linking to here from a home page with "topic 1", then I'd like to land on this page with "topic 1" open.

Comment: You mean if you click on some link say "index.html#topic1" then it should land to index.html with topic1 open or if the link is index.html#topic2 then topic2 should be open by default?

Comment: Yes, Exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the hash and

```
$(function(){

   var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
   showTopic(hash);

});

function showHash(s){
    if(s=="") return;
    $(".dt_"+s).trigger("click");
}
```

And change the html to

```
<dt data-id="123" class="dt_topic1">Topic 1</dt>
<dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</dd>

<dt data-id="124" class=dt_topic2"">Topic 2</dt>
<dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</dd>
```

i.e. just add a class on `dt`

And create links like `filename.html#topic1` or `filename.html#topic2`

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Quote doesn't come in either.

Comment: I hope that you have your previous code added to my code. And my code should be presend after your code.

Comment: Or can you tell me what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Yes, added your code to mine. I get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showTopic"